# Does ASP.NET Response Cache interacts with ASP.NET HttpRuntime Cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Are ASP.NET Response Cache and ASP.NET HttpRuntime.Cache completely different?

Is there any operation on the Response Cache that would affect HttpRuntime.Cache?

Greetz
Robert

Comment: Do you mean Response.Cache or do you mean response caching using OutputCache directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about you mean by *Response Cache* but AFAIK, there is only one cache store per ASP.NET application domain. Output caching also goes to the same cache store (however cache keys would be generated by ASP.NET based on url and cache policy).

`Response.Cache` is the [cache policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.aspx) object that allows you to query/control ASP.NET output caching problematically.

So to answer your question - Yes, output caching will definitely affect `HttpRuntime.Cache`. But its unlikely to affect the items that you had set manually because keys chosen by your are very unlikely to conflict with keys generated by ASP.NET runtime.

**EDIT**

One thing that I have missed to mention is that starting from .NET 4, output cache supports
provider model - so you can have your own [OutputCacheProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx) that can have a different store than runtime cache.

Comment: So everthing is stored in System.Web.Caching.Cache? Then in case of  cleanup my stuff and the cached responses would affected and removed in the same way (LRU) if? What cache Priority do the Response Cache entries have?

Comment: @RobertP., yes unless you have your own output cache provider (see my edit). So all cache items would be governed by same algorithm. I am not aware of exact cache priority for output cache items but my guess would the default value (normal). If you look at provider method signatures then they only offer expiry time - that would substantiate my claim for default priority value. OTOH, if you have a valid use case for avoiding same store/caching algo, then would suggest to build your own provider using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`

Comment: No need to seperate. Just wanted to know.